# Dynamic Method OpCodes.Stfld causing 'Operation could destabilize the runtime'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.5, dynamicmethod

I'm trying to upgrade a .Net 3.5 project to .Net 4.5, everything is working, but one DynamicMethod is causing an 'Operation could destabilize the runtime' exception

```
public static FieldSetter<TField> CreateSetFieldDelegate<TField>(FieldInfo fieldInfo)
{
    var dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod(
      "setfast_" + fieldInfo.Name,
      null,
      new[] { typeof(object), typeof(TField) },
      fieldInfo.DeclaringType);

    var ilGenerator = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();

    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);

    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldInfo);
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    return (FieldSetter<TField>)dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(FieldSetter<TField>));
}
```

The calling code

```
var fieldSetter = Reflection.CreateSetFieldDelegate<Guid>(_fieldInfo);

        return (dataProviderAdapter, target, values, index)
          => fieldSetter(target, dataProviderAdapter.GetGuid(values, index));
```

dataProviderAdapter.GetGuid(values, index) returns a system.Guid as expected, but invoking fieldSetter causes the 'Operation could destabilize the runtime' exception.

I don't have any experience with IL, so I'm really not sure where to start debugging this. PEVerify doesn't return any errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your field can be non public, you have to use another overload of DynamicMethod constructor to specify skipvisibilitycheck.